# How to check-in to TFS when all files have been replaced/removed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I am new to team foundation server and visual studio.

I have a non-VS project that I need to version control through TFS because of company policies. I use a different tool than TFS to edit my project, so when I was ready to push my changes I just checked out the project from TFS and cleaned out the local directory to replace with the new version of the project. I am now unable to check-in the changes because TFS is looking for the files that I deleted.

If I need to clean out and replace all files in a project, how can I check it in to TFS? Is there a way to force TFS to use my local version?

Comment: Which development tools are you using? What‘s  the  method you used to check in your project in TFS?

Comment: I just right clicked on the folder in TFS and "check-in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to do do **undo pending changes** for these deleted files. You can achieve it through Team Explorer or tf.exe command. In Team Explorer, select deleted files and click **Undo** All.You can also use tf undo command :

```
tf undo /workspace:"TheWorkspace";TheUser 
   $/MyProject" /server:MyServer /recursive
```

Then check in your new version of the project.

If you want to use Windows Explorer to manage TFS version control files, You need to:
First, create a workspace folder, put your project in this folder.
Then  use Windows Shell Extensions comming with [TFSPowerTools2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) to check in/check out files in the local workspace folder. 
[image]

Comment: I have a separate C# project  which I have been managing through TFS and VS entirely. Will an "undo all" action affect anything that's checked-in?

Comment: You can just undo pending changes for these deleted files, it  will only effect the pending changes, the file checked in will still in the source control with the version you checked out for edit.

Comment: I managed to check in everything by undoing all changes, removing all ols files and adding the new ones. However this was a very manual process. So whenever I rename/delete/add files I have to do this through VS? That's the only way?

Comment: If you are using other development tools such as Eclipse, there are some plug-in can help you to do the source control. Or you want use Windows Exploer to do it you can see above, whenever you rename/delete/add files  ,you can do it directly on the file.Then right click  the file select TeamFoundation Server →check in.